# Why does "entarten" not work in this sentence?

Tags: verb-usage, verb-choice

In conversation with 2 native speakers I said:

> In den Jahren seit seinem Tod ist Fatimas psychische Gesundheit entartet.

and they corrected me to:

> In den Jahren seit seinem Tod hat sich Fatimas psychische Gesundheit verschlechtert.

What is incorrect about the first sentence?

The English sentence I was attempting to translate is:

> In the years since his death, Fatima's mental health has degenerated.

Comment: Are you a real person? You questions always start with "In conversation with 2 native speakers I said:" then there is an example that is introducef by: " In conversation with 2 native speakers I said: ... they corrected me to ..." I think, that's a bot.

Comment: No, I am not a bot. But I do have a lot of conversations with these 2 native speakers.

Comment: @user44961 Yeah. Of course! And you like to use sentences like "In den Jahren seit seinem Tod ist Fatimas psychische Gesundheit entartet." And then you ask for help. Sorry, that I am so rude to doubt you!

Comment: Well, I understand your doubt. But it is true. The full story is that they want to learn Norwegian and I want to learn German. So I translate Norwegian lessons into English (with Google Translate) and then into German and they correct my German while practicing Norwegian. The lessons happen to be about the healthcare system in Norway. We do this once every week for going on 2 years. I am happy to provide additional documentation as you wish.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use the words "entarten" or "entarten" at all. At least since the nazis referred to modern art with the derisive term [entartete Kunst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_art), the words have somewhat of a taint. In general, I don't like to let those *bleep* decide which words I can and can't use, but "entartet" still feels kind of touchy.

Comment: So it's not a conversation but a mistranslation that we are supposed to correct.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Well, "entartet" has a very narrowly defined use in a math/computer science context, where an "entarteter Baum" is a tree (hierarchy) structure that does not actually fork into several branches at any point. Other than that, I agree the word has pretty much fallen out of use for the reasons described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Entarten"* is not a verb that can be used to describe the change of *"Gesundheit",* and it is not a valid translation of *"to degenerate".*

Valid translations for *"to degenerate"* are:

- degenerieren

  > Unsere westliche Gesellschaft ist zu einer Raff-Gesellschaft degeneriert.
- verkommen

  > Durch deinen Lebenswandel bist du gegenüber früher regelrecht verkommen.

More translations can be found on [leo.dict.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/to%20degenerate).

*"Entarten"* means to become something from a worse kind, class or species (Engl. *kind, species* = Germ. *Art*).

---

Verbs that can describe a change of healthiness are:

- verbessern

> Fatimas Gesundheit hat sich verbessert.
> <sup>Fatima's health has improved.</sup>

- verschlechtern

> Fatimas Gesundheit hat sich verschlechtert.
> <sup>Fatima's health has declined.</sup>

Her healthiness doesn't become something else. It just becomes worse without changing the fact that it still is healthiness.

Comment: Copied from Leo.dict.org: to degenerate (into sth.): zu etw. (or: in etw.) entarten

Comment: ""Entarten" means to become something from a worse kind, class or species" - I always understood it to mean that something leaves the boundaries of a definied species, compare "aus der Art schlagen".

Comment: Neither 'degenerieren' nor 'verkommen' are a good fit in German for a declining health of a person, even more so for what could be a 'psychischer Verfall'. Pity we don't know what OP wants to express.